How do I create partitions on Ubuntu Server?
Does anybody know how I am supposed to create a partition? I've tried to create one on SDA, but nothing happens, It just errors out saying: Permission Denied
I am using a "Dell PowerEdge R610" as my server.
Server partitions:

Error message:


You cannot edit mounted partitions, so in order to shrink a partition, you must first unmount it, and if it is a system partition you must boot from another operating system, for example a live USB drive. In Ubuntu Desktop and other systems with a graphical desktop, you can use gparted, which is rather easy to use. In Ubuntu Server you can use fdisk, gdisk or parted to edit partitions including creating partitions. gparted can also create file systems in them, while the other tools need separate tools to create file systems. All these tools need superuser privileges: run with sudo.

Note that Ubuntu server installations use LVM by default. Based on your screenshot it looks like your root logical volume does not occupy the whole of the /dev/sda3 physical volume - so there may be a possibility to create an additional LV there as an alternative to creating a traditional partition.

sudo fdisk /dev/sda

if your partition is already mounted you need to unmount it
if its not mounted you can try
sudo fdisk /dev/sda

you can use gparted in a usb or instead you can boot in any live linux distro to partition it
